# Functional equation (is solution unique)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

1. Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ - cont. diff. function. Is it true that equation $\cos{t}f(\sin{t})+\sin{t}f(\cos{t})=1, t \in [0,\pi/2]$ has only solution $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$? How can we prove the uniqueness?
2. Same question with $f$ just continuous.

Comment: Since f(sint) and f(cost) are periodic in t you could try an expansion in a Fourier series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ANALYSIS

Note that the related equation
$$
\cos(t)\cdot x+\sin(t)\cdot y=1
$$
defines a  *tangent to the unit circle* through the point $P=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$. Points on this tangent can be described by the vector function with coordinates
$$
\begin{align}
x(s)&=\cos(t)-s\cdot\sin(t)\\
y(s)&=\sin(t)+s\cdot\cos(t)
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore, we must arrange things so that $x(s)=f(\sin(t))$ and $y(s)=f(\cos(t))$ in order to match this related equation and the original problem. Therefore $f$ satisfies
$$
\sin(t)\longmapsto \cos(t)-s\cdot\sin(t)
$$
which is equivalent to $f(x)$ satisfying
$$
x\longmapsto \sqrt{1-x^2}-s\cdot x
$$
on the other hand, considering the second coordinate function, $f$ satisfies
$$
x\longmapsto \sqrt{1-x^2}+s\cdot x
$$

Substitute $s$ above by a continuous (possible differentiable) function of $x$. Then this is only consistent if $s(\sin(t))=-s(\cos(t))$. In particular we must have, since $\sin(0.25\pi)=\cos(0.25\pi)=0.5\sqrt 2$ that $s(0.5\sqrt 2)=0$. Then just pick your favourite function $s(x)$ with these properties. Differentiable, if you like.

Comment: More, precisely, the general continuous solution to $s(x)+s(\sqrt{1-x^2})=0$ with $s(1/\sqrt{2})=0$, is obtained by selecting an arbitrary continuous function $h:[0,1/\sqrt{2}]\to\Bbb{R}$ with $h(1/\sqrt{2})=0$ then defining $s$ by $$s(x)=\left\{\matrix{h(x)&\hbox{if}&0\leq x\leq 1/\sqrt{2}\cr -h(\sqrt{1-x^2})&\hbox{if}&(1/\sqrt{2})\leq x\leq 1}\right.$$

Comment: Yes, I believe our solutions agree now.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, this equation has infinitely many solutions. For example
$$
f_{\lambda}(x)=\left\{\matrix{\sqrt{1-x^2}+\lambda\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)&\hbox{ if}&0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\cr
\cr
\sqrt{1-x^2}+\lambda\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}-1\right)\qquad\quad\quad&\hbox{ if}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\leq x\leq 1.
}\right.
$$
is a solution for every $\lambda$.

Indeed, note that the quantity
$$G(t)=\cos t\, f_\lambda (\sin t)+\sin t\, f_\lambda(\cos t)$$ satisfy $G(t)=G(\frac{\pi}{2}-t)$, so, it is enough to show that $G(t)=1$ for $0\leq t\leq\frac{\pi}{4}$. For these values of $t$ we have $0\leq \sin t\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\leq\cos t\leq 1$, hence
$$
\eqalign{
f_\lambda(\sin t)&=\cos t+\lambda \tan t\,\left(1-\tan t\right)\cr
f_\lambda(\cos t)&=\sin t+\lambda \left(\tan t-1\right)
}
$$
So
$$
G(t)=1+\lambda(\sin t\,(1-\tan t)+\sin t\,(\tan t-1))=1.
$$
and the verification is complete.
$\qquad\square$

Comment: Sorry, but are not the terms involving $\lambda$ still slightly off? The two brackets seem correct, but I would say, they should be multiplied by $\lambda\cdot x$. Am I mistaken? I vote for your answer and hope you reply or fix it, regards

Comment: @String, as you see I just verified my calculation, it seems OK.

Comment: Thanks! That puzzles me ... Do you, by any chance, see an error in my analysis?

Comment: Ah, I see it now! Your version has simply been modulated with a factor $\frac{1}{\cos t}$ compared to what I suggested ... $\lambda$ could more generally be substituted by any function satisfying $\lambda(\cos t)=\lambda(\sin t)$ for the full solution. That $\lambda$-function being continuous (perhaps differentiable) as desired.